# getting the node value in phpquery

Tags: php, html, dom, phpquery

I am trying to get the node value from phpquery after scraping my html page.

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('myurl');

foreach($doc['#filter-reload.row h1'] as $value)
{
print_r($value);
exit;
}
```

I am getting output as

```
DOMElement Object ( [tagName] => h1 [schemaTypeInfo] => [nodeName] => h1 
[nodeValue] => Oz The Great And Powerful (PG) [nodeType] => 1 [parentNode] => (object value omitted) 
[childNodes] => (object value omitted) [firstChild] => (object value omitted) [lastChild] => (object value omitted) [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
```

I just want the nodeValue as output...But hw to get it ?

I tried:-

```
$doc['#filter-reload.row h1']->nodeValue //not working
$doc['#filter-reload.row h1']['nodeValue']//notworking
```

Comment: It will be easy if you convert it to array and print the value.

Comment: try $doc['#filter-reload.row h1'][0]->nodeValue. If it doesn't work plese post the value of print_r($doc['#filter-reload.row h1']);

Comment: @sarang nt possible i tried

Comment: @Rohit i have already showed the output above...Its of print_r only

Comment: you've shown the print_r($value). Please provide print_r($doc['#filter-reload.row h1']);

Comment: Its some very huge value..........

Comment: phpQueryObject Object ( [documentID] => f499db3ec781431fce22ea35c92d4eac [document] => DOMDocument Object ( [doctype] => (object value omitted) [implementation] => (object value omitted) [documentElement] => (object value omitted) [actualEncoding] => UTF-8 [encoding] => UTF-8 [xmlEncoding] => UTF-8 [standalone] => 1 [xmlStandalone] => ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out it will work.......

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('myurl');
$new_data = array();
foreach($doc['#filter-reload.row h1'] as $value)
{
    $new_data[] = $value->nodeValue;
}
```